# Selenium - Exception when trying to launch multiple instances with a specific profil

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to launch several instances of `Chromedriver` and use a specific chrom profile, the same for all of them.
I have no issue with he first instance.
But when I try to create a new instance then the exceptions says:

```
[2928:8456:0419/220244.606:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(21)] Unable to move the cache: Access is denied. (0x5)
[2928:8456:0419/220244.608:ERROR:cache_util.cc(138)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\ShaderCache\GPUCache to C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\ShaderCache\old_GPUCache_000
[2928:8456:0419/220244.618:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
[2928:8456:0419/220244.619:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(606)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
Opening in existing browser session.
```

Also if I create multiple instances without a profile specified then I have no issue.

I don't want to use a multi tab approach becaus eI tried it and it sets the focus every time you switch between tabs.

My c# code:

```
ChromeDriver chromeDriver = null;
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Name\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1");
chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```